# Closest distance from 3D point to vector line

Tags: 3d, mathematics, vector, linear-algebra

First let's have a look at my little drawing: 
[image]

I have an origin point *p1* defined by x, y and z co-ordinates, and a vector *v* given by x, y and z magnitude.

I also have an arbitrary point, *p2*, given by x, y and z co-ordinates, in the direction of the vector *v* from the origin point.

I need to calculate the closest distance *d* from the point *p2* to the line determined by the vector *v*. Put simply, I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=distance+from+point+to+line) gives tons of results for this.

Comment: Also [answered well at Math SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834426/distance-of-a-point-to-a-line).

Comment: In the time it took to create that drawing you'd have had your answer with basic searches on your own and moved beyond it to other, more fun aspects of your game!

Comment: Two postings from other SE sites. 1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438244/how-to-calculate-shortest-2d-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment-in-all

Comment: Thank you to those who provided constructive comments. I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing, I'm a complete math noob, and none of the things that I had found by searching (yes, I searched previously!) seemed to be very easily adaptable to my code. I appreciate now that there are quite a few methods that I can use to get what I'm trying to calculate!